# Syntax highlighting for regular expression literal

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

How would I prevent VS Code highlighting Javascript `regular expression literals` (forward slashes) as below?

[image]

I'd much rather have it highlighted similar to the string in the example.

Comment: Search for "Inspect TM Scopes" questions here.  Your scope is "string.regexp" so you can change its color with `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Nope :/ @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code open settings.json (through File > Preferences > Settings then look for "Edit in settings.json").
Thanks to editor.tokenColorCustomizations you can override color settings for predefined grammar scopes (the one you are interested in is string.regexp as answered by @Mark).

For instance

```
{  
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "source.js string.regexp",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#339999" // pick the color you want here
            }
        },
    ]
  }
}
```